# Limit Selectable Rows for MultiSelect in cxGrid (Developer Express)

Tags: delphi, grid, devexpress, rows

Does nybody know how to limit the number of rows the user can select in a cxGrid where MultiSelect is active?

The Grid is working in GridMode = True - because the amount of data is really big (200.000 rows). - Now if you press CTRL+A all rows are loaded because the grid wants to select them all.

Any tipps?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, JPS! Welcome to StackOverflow.  Nice question, too.  This one looks like it's gonna be a doozy.  The CX grid is one of the scariest pieces of lasagna code I've ever had to work with, and it's practically impossible to get anything useful done with it without digging through a ton of source code to try to find where the actual functionality is.

Comment: Lasagna? More like a basket full of onions - lots of different objects, you can peel off layer after layer, and sometimes you feel like crying. ;-)

Comment: cxDBData.pas : procedure TcxDBDataSelection.SelectAll;

That's where the action is.. and looking at the loop i think there is no event that can cancel the loading of all rows. - Maybe an abort in the canselectrow event will help, i'll let you guys know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your CanSelectRecord event -

```
if Sender.Controller.SelectedRecordCount > x then
    AAllow := False;
```

Where 'x' is the limit you want.

Comment: In Gridmode False this works perfeclty (but is not needed anyway, since strg+a is no problem) - now in Gridmode True the event is still called very often (i asume each row) but "SelectedRecordCount" sadly stays at Zero constantly.

Still the Event might be a good place to start. Maybe i find a counter that is going up somewhere in the data structure - or i might start my own counting when strg+a is pressed.

Comment: I just did my own counting in the event.. it won't cure the problem, because yes, i can disallow the selecting of each row. - But that doesn't stop the selection process. - The cxGrid continues to go through all rows and tries to select them. (So still everything is loaded and it takes forever)

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to deactivate Ctrl-A in your Form by creating a shortcut that would preempt it. Just an idea, but it should work.

Comment: This definitely a work arround, but since I am trying to create a component (derived form cxgrid) that we can use anywhere in our application i would really like to find a way to fix this inside the component.